# Como atribuir a variável do callback "cursor.toArray(err, doc)" para uma variável externa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, collection, callback

```
var result = [];
var user = db.collection('user');
var cursor = user.find();
cursor.toArray(function (err, doc) {
    result = doc;
});
console.log(result); // console -> []
```

Comment: Coloca uma *console.log* dentro do callback e veja se tem algum valor

Comment: Sim, quando eu coloco o console.log dentro do callback, o valor é atribuído perfeitamente. Porém, fora do callback, não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**O problema é apenas a Sincronização**

Você está tendo esse erro porque o método find () é assíncrono e, nesse caso, você tem uma Promisse que pode não ter sido resolvida antes do `console.log(result)`,

```
var result = [];
var user = db.collection('user');
var cursor = user.find(); 

//Aqui você tem uma Promisse
cursor.toArray(function (err, doc) {
    result = doc;
});
console.log(result);//Caso a Promisse não tenha sido executada ainda, result ainda é um Array vazio
```

Uma forma interessante de executar poderia ser assim, dependendo da sua versão do [Node](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/node-76-async-await):

```
async function getResults() {
    db.collection('user').find()
}

var results = await getResults();
results = results.toArray();
```

Dai seu código parece um código síncrono. A chave aqui é o comando async / await que aguarda os resultados da promessa. Mais informações, link https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas

Comment: Pois é... Realmente o problema é a sincronização mesmo, como você mencionou. Fiz alguns testes com async, await, conforme suas dicas, porém deu alguns erros aqui, mas acredito que seja relacionados aos pacotes npm ou alguma outra coisa relacionada ao node. Resolvia um erro e aparecia outro, então achei melhor adaptar minhas classes utilizando tudo dentro de callbacks mesmo até resolver essa questão. Mas vou continuar pesquisando sobre esse assunto de async e await. Achei interessante. Muito obrigado por responder minha questão. Valeu!!!

Comment: @LeandroSciola como eu disse depende da versão do node. Blz mano, da uma lida em *promisse* dai é tranquilo

Answer (score 0):

Ficou assim:

```
function find(query, callback) {

    db.collection('user').find(query).toArray(function (err, doc) {
        callback(err, doc);
    });
}

find({name: 'Leandro'}, function (err, doc) {

    let result = [];
    result['user'] = doc;
    console.log(result['user']); // console -> [ { name: 'Leandro', _id: 5a1d624e79a88f09fb805a35 } ]
});
```