# Alterando o valor de uma variável dentro de uma função nodejs

Tags: node.js

```js
userFoundId = undefined;
    const result = connection.query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = :name and 
    password = :password', data, (err, result) => {
        userFoundId = result[0].id //Valor alterado para 1
    });
connection.end();
console.log(userFoundId) //Display undefined
```

Como posso realizar uma busca de usuários dentro do banco mysql e o resultado da consulta ser salvo na variável userFoundId que será utilizado para realizar o login?

Comment: Basicamente, você não pode. Como o `connection.query` é assíncrono, o _callback_ dele será executado depois do `console.log(userFoundId)`, que está no fora do callback. Leia [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261866/como-atribuir-a-vari%C3%A1vel-do-callback-cursor-toarrayerr-doc-para-uma-vari%C3%A1ve) e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379212/como-atribuir-o-resultado-de-uma-promise-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel/379215#379215) para saber mais.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Como atribuir a variável do callback "cursor.toArray(err, doc)" para uma variável externa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261866/como-atribuir-a-vari%c3%a1vel-do-callback-cursor-toarrayerr-doc-para-uma-vari%c3%a1ve)